# Advanced math icon help in TeXlipse

Tags: math-mode, symbols, texlipse, auto-completion

As a regular user of Eclipse, I finally decided to give TeXlipse a shot. But I cant seem to find keyboard shortcuts or any sort of graphical menu or a popup such as content assist for advanced math symbols. For example, the "underbrace" symbol in this statement

```
$\underbrace{e^{i\pi}+1=0}_\text{i found it!}$
```

doesn't seem to figure anywhere in TeXlipse but it doesn't generate an error either if I use it. Among other useful short cuts, non-existent in TeXlipse, that I regularly use is "\\" for a newline in TexStudio (a fork of TexMaker).

Has anybody missed similar features in TeXlipse ?

Comment: The fact that a shortcut is not present doesn't mean that the LaTeX command is unusable. :) However you shouldn't use ``\\`` to end paragraphs, but rather an empty line.

Comment: @egreg, I do agree with you on the use of manual line breaks but do you get my point that there is no mention at all of an `\underbrace` (for example) in TeXlipse, whereas you find them easily in TeXmaker/TeXstudio/LyX...? Good code completion would require that you provide at least for what can be used.

Comment: Not sure exactly what kind of answer you're expecting here, shouldn't you rather submit this as a bug report/feature request to the TeXlipse developers?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. That is exactly what I did [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/forums/forum/451977/topic/5117423) but to no avail.

Comment: [This feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3399728&group_id=133306&atid=726821) (found under Tracker --> Feature requests on SourceForge) is perhaps relevant for you (though there is no apparent activity on it). And you could try bumping the thread you created in the forum, to try and get attention. Again though, I don't know what kind of answers you'd expect to get here.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. You have done just that ("answered my question") by pointing out similar feature requests from others. By the way, the [TeXlipse release notes](https://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?group_id=133306&release_id=415250) show that they are working on these improvements slowly and steadily...and thanks for your help.